# Write directory new entries to file periodically, keeping the ones that existed in the past

Tags: bash, file-system, shell

Some backup *Bash* script on my machine copies a specific directory entries filenames into a text file. Entries that no longer exist have to be kept (entries added during a previous run).

The script makes sure that entries which still exist will not be inserted twice in the backup file using *sort* and *uniq*.

```
local file=~/bar-entries.txt
touch "$file" "${file}_"
find ~/foo/bar -maxdepth 1 -type d \! -name bar | cat <"$file" - | sort | uniq > "${file}_"
mv "${file}_" "$file"
```

Can this code be optimized? Like can this scenario be achieved without relying on a temporary file? Any other improvement is welcome.

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sort's `-u` and `-o` switches:

```
find … | sort -u - $file -o $file
```

Answer (score 1):

Just maybe `rsync` for **remote synchronisation** might be attractive.

```
rsync --dryrun ...
```

Comment: Code in the question is part of a backup script which actually executes _rsync_ at some point. But prior to any rsync call, some commands have to be run like the one above which append entries from ~/foo/bar to the file not yet inserted.

Comment: Okay, so I did not need to mention rsync. (`-n` or.`--dryrun` has its uses.)

Comment: I am only looking for a way to avoid the use of a tempory file involved in the supplied few lines. _(That said, improvements of any kind are welcome)_

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the temporary file, if you open for append (i.e. `>>`), and use `comm` to find the non-duplicate lines (after sorting).